# How do you integrate $t\coth(x t)/\sqrt{1-t^2}$ from $t = 0$ to $1$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

How do you do this integral:

$$A=\int\limits_{0}^{1}\mathrm{d}t\frac{t}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}\coth(xt)$$

for a positive parameter x.

Comment: Why do you believe that there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: You have a point. In general, we don’t know right? Unless we try. I think it’s somehow related to Bessel functions and Struve functions.

Comment: This is a very interesting integral, in which context did you find it? I worked on it, there some relationship with my first posts, and I guess that Laplace could help

Comment: @stocha Hi stocha, thanks for your interest! This integral appears when one calculates the average internal energy of a linear chain of phonons. For such a system, the relation between the frequency and the wave number of phonon modes (dispersion relation) is $\omega = 2\omega_0\left|(sin(ka/2)\right|$. If you want, we could discuss more about this.

Comment: @Tschau Hi Mr. Tschau, thank you for your reply, sounds like you are a physicist, too. In my post below I did an integration concerning x to get it in the form of a generalized Schlömilch series. With each integration $\nu$ and $\mu$=$\nu+1$ increases. Mathematica has a problem with the convergence but if you follow the paper of A
RP´AD BARICZ AND TIBOR K. POG´ANY, see link below you can find helpful integral representations and also the Mellin transform.

Comment: The inverse Mellin transform seems only be done numerical, but I already tested approximate solutions. I tested another trick, I found for a similar problem but did not finished yet. The trick is to do the Laplace transform under the sum, then perform the summation, take the limit for $s$->$\infinity$ and do the inverse Laplace transform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the further treatment of the integral a little trick is needed:

$$\mathbf{A}\left( x\right) =\int_{0}^{1}\left( \int \frac{~t}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}%
\coth \left( x~t\right) dx\right) \;dt=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log \left( \sinh
\left( t~x\right) \right) }{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\;dt$$

where $\mathbf{A}\left( x\right) $ is the antiderivative of $A$.  We write $\mathbf{A}%
\left( x\right) $ in a series representation:

$$\mathbf{A}\left( x\right) =\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}\left(
t~x-\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\exp \left( -2n~t~x\right) }{n}\right) \;dt$$
Integration over $t$ leads to the generalized Schlömilch series
$$\mathbf{A}\left( x\right) =x-\frac{\pi }{2}T_{\nu ,\mu }^{I,L}\left(
x\right) $$
with

$$T_{\nu ,\mu }^{I,L}\left( y\right) =\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{I_{\nu }\left(
n~y\right) -L_{\nu }\left( n~y\right) }{n^{\mu }}$$

for $y=2x$,$\;\nu =0$ and $\mu =1$. $I_{\nu }$ and  $L_{\nu }$ are the modified Bessel function of the first kind and modified Struve function. In the end we have: 
$$A\left( x\right) =1-\frac{\pi }{2}\left( T_{\nu ,\mu }^{I,L}\left( x\right)
\right) ^{\prime }$$

The Integral can further be simplified using the Sonin-Gubler formula as
discussed in detail in  [POG´ANY](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/235622755_Integral_representations_and_summations_of_the_modified_Struve_function)